# How to make spinning/rotate an entity in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I want to make my `entity` spinning/rotating in Y-axis.
I tried like this:

```
  <a-entity position="-1 0.5 3" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 0 0 ; loop: true; elasticity:1000; dur: 10000" rotation="90 0 0">
    <a-box position="1 0 3" height="0" rotation="0 0 0" color="red"></a-box>
  </a-entity>
```

I also tried to make with animation tag, but this isn't right around the axis. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup rotates a frame of reference with a box from `90 0 0` to `0 0 0`.

If you want to rotate the box around its axis, attach the animation component to the box:

```
<a-box position='' rotation='' animation=''></a-box>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ey17rfz4/2/).

---

If you want it to rotate another axis (Y) then you need the change to be made within the
 Y axis: `0 90 0` to `0 0 0`:

```
<a-entity animation='from: 0 90 0; to: 0 0 0'>
   <a-box></a-box>
</a-entity>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey17rfz4/1/).

Comment: Thank you, I got it, so if I attach the animation attribute to an element then it will do it, but if the container element then it will change the animation as the container is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo that shows how to spin an object by rolling over it with the cursor. It does not use animation, but alters the rotation a bit every frame. 
https://glitch.com/~rollover-rotate